# A good word for a "tough journey full of rich experiences"

Tags: word-choice, idioms, synonyms

I am at loss for a word/phrase/idiom that captures the situation of a person having been on a difficult journey yet replete with fruitful/rich experiences. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**:

An example which captures the situation I want to describe is Duke Senior speaking highly of country life after he was faced with great hardships during his exile in the forest of Eden(As you like it by Shakespeare). Also I am looking for a more or less sharp but mild phrase, say something that one can write in an SOP(Statement of Purpose) for a graduate program.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Odyssey sounds good

Comment: @RegDwigнt Also I don't understand why I got a downvote. I am new to this SE. Is this not an appropriate question for this site?

Comment: take the tour of the site;  edit in some research you have done of your own question.  Start with what you have found in say ... dictionaries.

Comment: *Quest*? Please expand your question to indicate what words you've considered and rejected and why. Otherwise, we're just presenting random suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

How about ‘epic’ - as in an ‘epic adventure’ with it’s suggestion of cinematic sweeping landscapes, challenges met, extremes encountered, and stories to tell?

It really means ‘a long story with many chapters’ so that might fit quite well. It also encapsulates ‘heroic’.

Epic:

a long poem, typically one derived from ancient oral tradition, narrating the deeds and adventures of heroic or legendary figures or the history of a nation.
synonyms:   heroic poem; More
adjective
1.
relating to or characteristic of an epic or epics.
"England's national epic poem Beowulf"
synonyms:   heroic, long, grand, monumental, Homeric, Miltonian

Answer (score 1):

When discussing life's rich tapestry of trials, tribulations and experiences we will often encapsulate that by simply paraphrasing as **"Life's Journey"** or **"Journey of Life"**

**Life is a journey**. When we stop, things don't go right. [Pope Francis]

**Life's journey** bends, but only two ends. [Anon]

In the **journey of life**, we pass pleasures & pain. There will be sunshine and rain; there will be loss and gain. But we must learn to smile again. [RVM]

Looking through such statements as you mention one word that recurs over and over is "experience" I will often refer to my varied training as that hackney phrase "University of Life".

Combining the two concepts
"As they pass through the University on their journey of life our students can expect to experience the wonders and challenges that academia has to offer"